# Вхождение объектов в заданную выделенную область

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Нужно, чтобы после выделения области на карте, прорисовывались объекты, попавшие в эту область. Область выделяю через geometryEditor.Polygon. С точками проблем нет. Все отрисовывается. Хороший пример здесь: https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/show_visible_objects

А как быть с полигонами? Попробовал - была невнятная ругань про границы. Как вариант, можно было бы проверять на вхождение только одной вершины(например первой[0]). Но тогда ее нужно описывать, как точку. И теряется инфа об объекте.

Answer (score 2):

Вот пример, на карте появляется полигон если он полностью попадает в другой полигон.

```
var objects = ymaps.geoQuery([{ "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [тут координаты]}]);
objects.addToMap(myMap);
var polygon = new ymaps.Polygon([
    [
        [54.78000432402266,36.84172564285271],
        [56.78000432402266,36.84172564285271],
        [56.78000432402266,38.84172564285271],
        [54.78000432402266,38.84172564285271],
        [54.78000432402266,36.84172564285271]
    ]
]);
// Добавляем многоугольник на карту.
myMap.geoObjects.add(polygon);

// Включаем режим масштабирования.
polygon.editor.startFraming();
polygon.events.add('geometrychange', function () {
    // После каждого изменения полигона будем проверять попадает ли он в другой.
    var visibleObjects = objects.searchInside(polygon).addToMap(myMap);
    // Оставшиеся объекты будем удалять с карты.
    objects.remove(visibleObjects).removeFromMap(myMap);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9r7z5j1v/

Comment: se0ga, спасибо за ответ. Только ты сначала добавляешь полигон на карту. Мне же нужно, чтобы полигоны добавлялись на карту после попадания в выделенную область. Но так не получается. Ошибка "geometry.component.getBoundsFromPixels: Расчет границ не возможен без добавления на карту."

Comment: Их можно просто скрывать к примеру https://jsfiddle.net/8d0nvtqs/

Comment: И снова нужна помощь все по тому же вопросу. Есть прямоугольная область с координатами зданий (полигоны), включающая в себя границы города (контур в виде полигона). Мне нужны здания только внутри города. Все остальное отсечь. objects = ymaps.geoQuery(polygons);   visibleObjects = objects.searchInside(plgn).addToMap(map); где objects весь массив зданий.  visibleObjects  все равно рисует объекты за границами города...

Comment: Пример выше не помогает, там ровно то что вам нужно. Плюс посмотрите на этот пример https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/placemarks_in_circle

Comment: Спасибо за помощь.  Оказывается все нормально работало. Просто в одной переменной ошибся и тянул кривые данные... )))))